# Laravel 5.6 changing the timestamps

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

A noob question:
I have not been successful changing my timestamps in Laravel. I even went into my Model.php to change my timestamps but still not successful. Hope someone can guide me on this matter. As I would like to change my timestamp to:

const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';

const UPDATED_AT = 'last_update';

Below is the my Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Events extends Model
{

    const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'last_update';

    public function event_type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\EventsType');
    }


    public function time(){
        $this->hasMany('App\Time');
    }

    // protected $fillable = [

    //     'name', 'description','date_of_event','location','is_Active',

    // ];

}
```

My migration is below:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateEventsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('event_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->datetime('date_of_event');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->text('location');
            $table->text('note');
            $table->boolean('is_Active');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('events');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel provides timestamp management automatically
You just have to include this at the end of your schema create method

```
$table->timestamps();
```

this will give you two columns in table 'created_at' and 'updated_at'. they are self explanatory. they are automatically managed when you create or update any record.

if you want to manage timestamps on your own then

```
$table->datetime('creation_date');
$table->datetime('last_update');
```

in this case you have to fill these values manually when you create or update records.

Hope this clears your concept.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamps() creates two DATETIME columns to store the timestamps. The names of the created columns will be default (created_at and updated_at).

If you want need custom timestamp columns you will have to create them by yourself as samo already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 8.x

Migration file :

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateDataTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('data', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('data');
    }
}
?>
```

Model File :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Data extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];
}
?>
```

Inserting Data :

```php
use App\Models\Data;
 
$insertData= Data::create([
    'name' => 'Name Data Here',
    'created_at' => '2022-10-09 16:17:18', //date('Y-n-d G:i:s') or date('Y-n-d G:i:s','timestamphere')
    'created_at' => '2022-10-09 16:17:18',
]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).